# How to define constrains for multiple different generic types

Tags: .net

I have following interfaces defined

```
interface IStoreItem
{

}

interface ILoadItem
{

}
```

Now I would like to implement a collection which can handle items of these interafeces but usually a class which realises IStoreItem will not realise ILoadItem. So is there some way I can define a constrain like this:

```
public class NetworkingCollection<T> : List<T>
   where T : IStoreItem or ILoadItem
{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported.

You will need a different class for each interface you want to constrain to.

---

Alternatively, if you inherit `IStoreItem` and `ILoadItem` from a common interface (say `IGenericItem`), you could constrain to the parent interface.

Comment: Ok, I expected this answer. Thank you.